# React / Javascript map function - return array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of accounts with a load of properties on each account. I need to send a cut down version, with an array of only two fields, to a method. I have to pass a property called `options` to my SelectInput component, which has a list of ids and values, which land up rendereing a drop down.

```
<SelectInput 
    options={
       this.value.allAccountsList
          .map((item, index) => {
                          new { 
                            id: item.Id,
                            value: item.name
                          }
                      })  
                    }/>
```

But am getting:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Is map the right thing to use here, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: map is correct to use in this requirement, only problem is remove new with return

var newData = this.value.allAccountsList.map((item, index) => {
 return {id: item.Id,
                            value: item.name}
})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` is the right thing, yes. The problem is the `new` keyword. You don't use `new` when creating an object with an object literal. Another problem is that your arrow function has no return value. Fixing both, just change `new` to `return`:

```
<SelectInput 
    options={
        this.value.allAccountsList
        .map((item, index) => {
            return { 
                id: item.Id,
                value: item.name
            };
        })  
    }
/>
```

You can also use the concise form of arrow function, by using `()` around the object literal. If we also remove the `index` parameter (since it isn't used):

```
<SelectInput 
    options={
        this.value.allAccountsList.map(i => ({id: i.Id, value: i.name}))
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `new` inside the map callback.

Try this:

```
<SelectInput 
    options={
       this.value.allAccountsList
          .map((item, index) => ({
                            id: item.Id,
                            value: item.name
                      }))  
                    }/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this,

```
new { 
   id: item.Id,
   value: item.name
}
```

do this,

```
return { 
 id: item.Id,
 value: item.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace **new** with **return** that should take care of it. So map callback should return value with new you are not returning the value which is causing the error message

One more suggestion instead of inline code in component to transform data try extracting it out and using it that really helps simplify code to read and maintain

```
<SelectInput 
    options={
       this.value.allAccountsList
          .map((item, index) => {
                          return { 
                            id: item.Id,
                            value: item.name
                          }
                      })  
                    }/>
```